# Calculate employee turnover rate by month in Postgres/Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, data-science, data-analysis

I have a Rails/PostgreSQL web app, with an employees table in the following format:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: employees
#
#  id                  :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  first_name          :string
#  last_name           :string
#  hired_datetime      :datetime
#  terminated_datetime :datetime
```

I'd like to produce an employees retention rate by month graph, like the following (but by all 12 months or maybe the last 12 months):
[image]

How can I generate a query (with ActiveRecord or straight SQL) to produce the data needed for this graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep the year, month combination, I would suggest date_trunc, otherwise date_part. [Here's the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-datetime.html)

```
date_trunc('month', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')    2001-02-01 00:00:00
date_part('month', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')     2
```

From there, you can create aggregate functions like `count`.

```
SELECT count(*), date_trunc('month', terminated_datetime) 
FROM employees
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', terminated_datetime);
```

Or, in a later query, if you're looking for the specific employee records (including first, last, etc) in December of 2018:

```
SELECT *, date_trunc('month', terminated_datetime) 
FROM employees 
WHERE date_trunc('month', terminated_datetime) = '2018-12-01 00:00:00';
```

Then again, you might look at all of the employees who left in December (regardless of year):

```
SELECT *, date_part('month', terminated_datetime) 
FROM employees 
WHERE date_part('month', terminated_datetime) = 12;
```